# Categorisation/matching of stores

Tags: python

i want to write a python code to do the categorisation of store names(chemist,restaurent etc) automatically.

if the store name is Anand Medical store it should fall in chemist cat., if it is 7 General store it should fall in General store cat.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing this? Refer [help] on asking good questions. Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is, but if you are looking for a suggestion on how to achieve it then please find below my thought.

If you have a list of words that represent different store categories, you can create a dictionary with those words as keys and the corresponding store categories as values.

When you want to categorize a store name, iterate through the above dictionary and search for each key in the store name, when you find a match then assign the category corresponding to that key to the store name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use regexes to categorize:

```
import re
from enum import Enum


class Store(Enum):
    UNKNOWN = 1
    CHEMIST = 2
    RESTAURANT = 3
    GENERAL = 4


CHEMIST_STORE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'.*medical|chemist.*', re.IGNORECASE)
RESTAURANT_STORE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'.*restaurant.*', re.IGNORECASE)
GENERAL_STORE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'.*general.*', re.IGNORECASE)


def classify_store(store: str) -> Store:
    if CHEMIST_STORE_PATTERN.search(store):
        return Store.CHEMIST
    if RESTAURANT_STORE_PATTERN.search(store):
        return Store.RESTAURANT
    if GENERAL_STORE_PATTERN.search(store):
        return Store.GENERAL
    return Store.UNKNOWN


def main() -> None:
    store_to_classify = input('Enter store to classify (for testing only): ')
    print(classify_store(store_to_classify))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter store to classify (for testing only): Anand Medical store
Store.CHEMIST
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter store to classify (for testing only): 7 General store
Store.GENERAL
```